# an array does not get a value

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with the following code

```
public static void SideBet(int numberDice,int bet,int money) {
        System.out.println("You established a " + "\""+ "point" + "\"" + ". " + "Your " + "\""+ "point" + "\"" + " is " + numberDice + ". " + "You have to roll a(n) " + numberDice + " to win your bet, "+ bet +" chips." );

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You can put side bets for 4,5,6,8,9 or 10.");
        SideBetChoice = Console.readLine("Would you like to make any side bets ? (Type " + "\""+ "Yes" + "\"" + " or "+ "\""+ "No" + "\"" + ", then hit Enter.)");

        int s = 0;
        int r = 0;

           if (SideBetChoice.equals("Yes")) {
                System.out.println("You can put as many side bets as you would like for the numbers 4,5,6,8,9 or 10.");
                int SideBetNumber = Console.readInt("How many side bets would you like to make ? (Introduce a number, minimum 1, maximum 6.)");

                int[] SBNArray = new int[SideBetNumber];
                int[] sbArray = new int[SideBetNumber];


                    for (s = 0; s <= (SideBetNumber -1) ; s++) {
                       SBNArray[s] = Console.readInt("On which number would you like to put a side bet ?");
                       sbArray[s] = Console.readInt("Currently you have " + money + " chips, how much would you like to bet ?");
                       money = money - sbArray[s];
                       System.out.println("Thank you for your " +sbArray[s]+ " chip side bet on number " +SBNArray[s]+".");
                       System.out.println();
                    }

           } 
           if (SideBetChoice.equals("No")) {
                return;
           }
```

sbArray and SBNArray does not get a value and it keeps crashing ... 
Can anyone help me out and tell me what is wrong, why the 2 arrays do not get a value, therefor they are null ?

Comment: SideBetChoice is never declared with a type. Was it declared earlier in the program?

Comment: what is `Console`? if it is `java.io.Console` i dont think it has a `readInt` method. is it a `Scanner` instance..? if so, it is `nextInt` and not `readInt`

Comment: public static Console input = new Console();   The Console has no problem ...I will check the SideBetChoice

Comment: public static String SideBetChoice = ""; declared in the main as a string

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Answer (score 0):

There is no readInt()-method in Console.
Also I'm not sure if you're using console correctly, it should look like this:

```
Console console = System.console();

console.readLine("Type something");
```

Just use readLine() and convert it to an int:

```
    Console console = System.console();

    String input = console.readLine("Type a number");
    try
    {
        int myNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("This ain't a number!");
    }
```

Also please never use Capital Letters for Variables' Names or method-names, it's very confusing because you could think it would be a Class or a Type.
So please change the name of SBNArray and SideBetNumber, SideBetChoice etc. etc.
Only Constants should be written with only Capital Letters and Classes and Types start with Capital Letters.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, it seems that you're using BreezyGUI.Console, therefore there is a readInt()-method.

Could you give more information?
I'd like to know if the text of the readInt() is even displayed.